# Hide element when click outside element?

Tags: javascript

**Problem :**

- I know there are many answer for detecting clicks outside an element.
- But I don't now how to hide the element when the click outside of the element happens in this code.

**Scenario :**

- In this code I add to all li elements a click function. This function
  shows the child element.
- How can I **detect a click outside with pure
  javasctipt using for loop to hide the element**.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (lis[i].children.length > 0) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      lis[i].children[0].style.display = 'block';
    });
  }
  }
```

```css
 li, ul {
  width: max-content;
 }
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list
    <ul>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>list</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>list
    <ul>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>list</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Start by doing this: `if (this.children.length>0) this.children[0].style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Do you want the top level `<li>` to also hide, or just all children?

Comment: @seebiscuit What is top level <li> ?

Comment: There are two levels of `<li>`. What should hide when you click outside an element. The first level, the ones under the first `<ul>`, or only the second level (the children of the first level `<li>`)?

Comment: @seebiscuit I want to hide the children of the first level <li>

Comment: @mplungjan I can't understand?

Comment: Your code gave error when no children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution helped me.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (lis[i].children.length > 0) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
      lis[i].children[0].style.display = 'block';
    });
  }
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li').forEach(function(item) {
      item.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'none'
    })
  })
```

```css
li, ul {
 width: max-content;
}

ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul>
  <li>parent1
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent2
    <ul>
      <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent3
    <ul>
      <li>child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure javaScript below code will help you.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

document.getElementById("menuContainer").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  if(lis[i].children[0]){
    lis[i].children[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li" && event.target.children[0]){
    event.target.children[0].style.display = (event.target.children[0].style.display == 'block')?'none':'block';
  }
});
```

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul id="menuContainer">
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list
    <ul>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>list</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>list
    <ul>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>list</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update your script with this:

```
    let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

    for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            $('li').children().css("display", "none");
            if (lis[i].children.length > 0) {    
                lis[i].children[0].style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    }
```